# Autonomous Robot Power Supply Redesign

Tags: power-supply, batteries, raspberry-pi

I am getting started in electronics/robotics by making a Raspberry Pi robot. I have a (somewhat) working prototype but realized that I need to have a single rechargeable power source. Currently, I have the Pi, sensors, and two servos working out of a 3.7V battery that is connected into a PowerBoost 1000 DC-DC boost converter. I am aware that powering servos off the Pi is not ideal--I plan to change this layout in the next design.

The robot also has two DC motors that are connected to another source, a 5 AA battery pack that feeds a L298N Motor driver. I made a diagram to illustrate the current setup:

[image]

I thought of using the built-in voltage regulator in the L298N to feed the Pi and sensors/servos but from what I understand, this is a linear regulator which is inefficient.

I really need to add into my design something similar to the PowerBoost charger that allows me to supply power to all my components, use a single battery pack, and that is rechargeable (via USB).

Assuming everything is being powered with 5 volts, I roughly estimated the power usage:

- Pi Zero W (no display, no bluetooth, Wi-fi, camera connected): ~120mA
- 2 x TT Motors (155mA no load, 1.2A stalled): ~1.2A
- 2 x SG90 9g Servos (10mA Idle, 360mA stalled): ~360mA
- HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor: ~15mA
- Pi Camera 1.3 (100mA Idle, 240mA recording): ~170mA

That's around 1.865A@5V, so around 9.3W? I need a battery that could handle this load, with some extra headroom just in case, and is **easily rechargeable without removing the battery from the robot**. I don't expect all components to be powered on at the same time though.

Any suggestions/feedback is appreciated.

Comment: get switching regulators and don't skimp on capacitors downstream of them.  Use diodes and or switches to control charging vs discharging the battery.  A pretty electrically efficient mechanism is having the connection of the charging cable flip a mechanical switch!

Comment: Another way of looking at it is, about 8W for the motors, plus a little for everything else. A 2S Lithium battery will handle the motors easily, with enough to spare for a buck convertor to 5V or 3.3V for the control stuff.

Comment: @user_1818839 thanks for your input. 2S batteries look like an attractive alternative... but what other batteries would you recommend? I looked up 2S batteries like the ones you would use in RC cars but from what I've read, they are not recommended to be charged without supervision. My project may require to be charged overnight without anyone nearby.